# Sunburst Oracle JET Data Binding

Tags: oracle-apex, sunburst-diagram, oracle-jet

I am trying to use Oracle JET sunburst in my APEX web application. I want my sunburst to change label(language) based on toggling of a switch.

Each time the switch toggles, an Ajax call is fired up and comes back with appropriate JSON result.

I could verify that after toggle of switch, the JSON file returns with corresponding language content but the problem is that only the label of kernel node will change and the rest will remain as before(previous language).

### The code for ViewModel:

```
function sunburstDraw(process_name, sunburst_id, lang){
     require(['knockout', 'ojs/ojbootstrap', 'ojs/ojarraytreedataprovider','ojs/ojknockout-keyset', 'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojsunburst', 'ojs/ojbutton'],

     function(ko, Bootstrap, ArrayTreeDataProvider, keySet) {
          function SunburstModel() {
              var self = this;                                      
              self.langValue = ko.observable(lang);                                                                  
              self.jsonData = ko.observableArray();
              self.sunburstData = new ArrayTreeDataProvider(self.jsonData, {keyAttributes: 'id', childrenAttribute: "nodes"});

              ko.computed(function() {
                apex.server.process(
                        "sunburstData",
                        {x01: self.langValue()},
                        {
                         dataType: "text",
                         success:function(pData)
                         {
                          self.jsonData(JSON.parse(pData));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                          document.getElementById("mysun").refresh();
                         }                                                      
                        }                                                                                                             
                   );

              }).extend({ deferred: true });   
            };

      var sunburstModel = new SunburstModel();             
      Bootstrap.whenDocumentReady().then(
           function() {
              ko.applyBindings(sunburstModel, document.getElementById(sunburst_id));
           });

    });

}
```

### Code for HTML View:

```
<div id='sunburst_container'>
    <oj-buttonset-one class="oj-buttonset-width-auto" value="{{langValue}}">
         <oj-option value="EN">EN</oj-option>
         <oj-option value="FA">FA</oj-option>      
    </oj-buttonset-one>

    <oj-sunburst id="mysun"
        data="[[sunburstData]]">
        <template slot='nodeTemplate'>
           <oj-sunburst-node
               label='[[$current.data.label]]'
               value='[[$current.data.val]]'>
           </oj-sunburst-node>
        </template>
    </oj-sunburst>
</div>
```

In a second attempt:

To get rid of the complexity of asynchronous Ajax call, I removed the apex.server.process function and replaced it with below hard-coded lines. I get error of "This is null" and it is due to the line:(I think, I should bind it to an object)
document.getElementById("mysun").refresh();

### Hardcoded ViewModel:

```
function sunburstDraw(process_name, sunburst_id, lang){
     require(['knockout', 'ojs/ojbootstrap', 'ojs/ojarraytreedataprovider','ojs/ojknockout-keyset', 'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojsunburst', 'ojs/ojbutton'],

     function(ko, Bootstrap, ArrayTreeDataProvider, keySet) {
          function SunburstModel() {
              var self = this;                                      
              self.langValue = ko.observable(lang);                                                                  
              self.jsonData = ko.observableArray();
              self.sunburstData = new ArrayTreeDataProvider(self.jsonData, {keyAttributes: 'id', childrenAttribute: "nodes"});

              ko.computed(function() {
               if(self.langValue() == "EN")
                   self.jsonData([{"label":"Iran", "id":"1", "val":34, "nodes":[{"label":"Tehran", "id":"2", "val":31, "nodes":[]}]}]);                                
               else
                   self.jsonData([{"label":"ایران", "id":"1", "val":34, "nodes":[{"label":"تهران", "id":"2", "val":31, "nodes":[]}]}]);
               document.getElementById("mysun").refresh();                                                                     

              }).extend({ deferred: true });   
            };

      var sunburstModel = new SunburstModel();             
      Bootstrap.whenDocumentReady().then(
           function() {
              ko.applyBindings(sunburstModel, document.getElementById(sunburst_id));
           });

    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @vas if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself

Answer (score 2):

Nice catch!

It seems to be a bug where `self.jsonData()` is not getting completely updated with the new values. I was able to solve by adding `self.jsonData([]);` at the starting of the ko.computed function.

```
ko.computed(function() {

    self.jsonData([]);

    if(self.langValue() == "EN")
       self.jsonData([{"label":"Iran", "id":"1", "val":34, "nodes":[{"label":"Tehran", "id":"2", "val":31, "nodes":[]}]}]);                                
    else
       elf.jsonData([{"label":"ایران", "id":"1", "val":34, "nodes":[{"label":"تهران", "id":"2", "val":31, "nodes":[]}]}]);                                                                    

}).extend({ deferred: true });
```

Btw, the component will work fine without the `refresh()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for responding late and thanks for your help. I was able to solve the issue 2 weeks ago, therefore I have not checked stackoverflow. I posted the following on Oracle community:

I found the problem by luck. It comes form this line of code:

self.sunburstData =  new ArrayTreeDataProvider(self.jsonData, {keyAttributes: 'id', childrenAttribute: "nodes"});

I had put 'id' as keyAttributes instead of 'label'. Since when we change language, the ids will remain the same and only labels will change, the OJET code does not recognize the need for refresh of sunburst diagram. This causes misbehavior and only label of kernel node will be updated. (I think OJET team should address this issue).

After changing: keyAttributes: 'label', it works perfectly. But it introduces another issue in my case. The reason I set keyAttributes to 'id' instead of 'label' in first place was that my labels are not unique and during drilling it causes namespace collision.

Just a minor feedback:
calling refresh() or not calling it, that is not the problem!